Is set.seed() needed when building a single decision tree in R?
I am learning how to build a single decision tree and random forests in R. I understand that set.seed() is needed before building a random forest to ensure reproducibility of the results, e.g. if someone uses my code, they will get the same output because the same random forest trees will be produced.
However, since a single decision tree is only based on one tree, do I still need to use set.seed() before building it? Will the resulting tree not always be the same, when the same code and dataset is used, no matter if I use set.seed() or not?
I have build a single decision tree using:
> tree <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., method='class', data=kyphosis)
> printcp(tree)

I have tried running this script with and without putting set.seed(101) in the preceding line. In both cases I got the same output:
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Age   Start

Root node error: 17/81 = 0.20988

n= 81 

CP nsplit rel error xerror    xstd
1 0.176471      0   1.00000 1.0000 0.21559
2 0.019608      1   0.82353 1.0588 0.22010
3 0.010000      4   0.76471 1.0588 0.22010

So it seems set.seed() is not needed, but could anyone help me understand if I am indeed correct about this, and what the rationale behind this idea is? Thanks!
p.s. I do understand that single decision trees are not very desirable in general (compared to random forests), but was still curious

set.seed is not needed since there is no randomness involved in simple decision tree.

As others have mentioned set.seed is needed whenever the function under consideration is using any form of randomness. Thus, you will need to look into the source code of the function to see whether there is some randomness involved.
This is not a trivial task, because the randomness can be hidden deeply in some nested calls and one also need to know which functions are in fact non deterministic.
One potential way of checking whether any function used randomness is to monitor .Random.seed:

‘.Random.seed’ is an integer vector, containing the random number
generator (RNG) state for random number generation in R.

That is we can check whether .Random.seed changes. We can use trace to check the state at each step of the function.
In your case:
library(rpart)

## call random function once to set seed initially
invisible(sample(10))

## sample functions to showcase the idea
no_random <- function(x) {
  if (x > 5) {
    x <- 2 * x
  }
  x
}
random <- function(x) {
  if (x > 5) {
    x <- sample(10, 1) * x
  }
  x
}

trace_seed <- function() {
  initial <- .Random.seed
  i <- 0L
  function() {
    i <<- i + 1
    if (!identical(initial, .Random.seed)) {
      cat("Random seed changed in step", i - 1L, "\n")
      initial <<- .Random.seed
    }
  }
}

ts <- trace_seed()
trace("no_random", tracer = ts, at = seq_along(body(no_random)), print = FALSE)
no_random(10) ## no message
untrace("no_random")

ts <- trace_seed()
trace("random", tracer = ts, at = seq_along(body(random)), print = FALSE)
random(2) ## no message
untrace("random")

ts <- trace_seed()
trace("random", tracer = ts, at = seq_along(body(random)), print = FALSE)
random(10) ## Random seed changed in step 2 
untrace("random")

trace(rpart, tracer = ts, exit = ts, at = seq_along(body(rpart)), print = FALSE)
## no message thus likely to be deterministic
invisible(rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., method = "class", data = kyphosis)) 
untrace("rpart") 

N.B. I would consider this check rather a hack giving you a first idea rather than a general solution, because the state of the random generator may change even if it has no impact on the output, or randomness is generated in some C code without effecting the R random state (ven though this seems to be a bad practice).

See also Who is touching the .Random.seed?
